# How to set animations on application start in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, animation

How can I set animations in app delegate class?

Comment: please Elaborate your question

Comment: what is so ambigous and not clear?? I just want to add an animation transition like "TransitionFlipFromLeft", when the app will appear from when it is launched

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can show an animation just after your application loaded.

If you want to animate your "Default.png" to fade out for example when your application loaded, try this :

In **AppNameAppDelegate.h** :

```
#import UIKit/UIKit.h

@interface AppNameAppDelegate : NSObject  {
    UIImageView *splashView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context;

@end
```

In **AppNameAppDelegate.m** :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
    splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
    [_window addSubview:splashView];
    [_window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    //Set your animation below
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:_window cache:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector (startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
    splashView.frame = CGRectMake(-60, -60, 440, 600); 
    splashView.alpha = 0.0; 
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    return YES;
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context {
    [splashView removeFromSuperview];
    [splashView release];
}
```

I'm not sure if it's what are you looking for but maybe...

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...
I think you will have to be a bit clearer.
You are not able to set an animation as the absolute first point of you application.
You can add an image named "Default.png" that will be shown when you application is loading.

There should be no major problems with showing an animation in you AppDelegate, but it will only sho AFTER your application is loaded.

Comment: what is so ambigous and not clear?? I just want to add an animation transition like "TransitionFlipFromLeft", when the app will appear from when it is launched